# Linking external static library in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I made a Qt Project with two sub-projects. One is a static library, the other is the GUI app that uses the static library.

Since this is a sub-project project I have specified the order in which the two parts are built. Starting with the static library in the project tree and then the app in the project tree. Done with the CONFIG+=ordered option.

I also require a third external static library. Which is in a separate directory on my system.

So for both the sub projects I add the following to both of the .pro files:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/include
LIBS += -L/local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/lib -lbpp-seq -lbpp-core
```

Then for the app subproject I used the Add Library wizard to link a library that is in the project tree.

I've written a very basic GUI with a few labels and a File menu, to test everything is working.

Clicking the green run button results in the successful running of the app and the test functionality works well.

However, when I come to the build folder, double click on the executable, nothing happens. I open terminal and try to launch it again:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libbpp-seq.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm having trouble understanding this as .so are shared objects, I would have thought it would be .a for the static file, I'm also confused why running with the Green Arrow 'Run' in Qt Creator would work and run the program, but trying from the executable results in the above error. Is there something else I need to do?

EDIT:

The 3rd party library tells how to link either dynamically or statically with g++ commands.

Dynamic Linkage:

```
g++ biohello.cpp \
    -o biohello \
    -I$bpp_dir/include \
    -L$bpp_dir/lib \
    -lbpp-seq -lbpp-core
```

Static Linkage:

```
g++ biohello.cpp \
    -o biohello \
    --static \
    -I$bpp_dir/include \
    -L$bpp_dir/lib \
    -lbpp-popgen -lbpp-phyl -lbpp-seq -lbpp-core
strip biohello
```

I've been able to statically link the libraries for command line programs with the second g++ command. I'd like to achieve the same but with Qt Creator for the gui app.

UPDATE:

Removing the Two lines used:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/include
LIBS += -L/local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/lib -lbpp-seq -lbpp-core
```

from both .pro files and trying the Add Library wizard to add the .a files externally, resulting in the addition of:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/release/ -lbpp-seq
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/debug/ -lbpp-seq
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/ -lbpp-seq

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/include

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/release/libbpp-seq.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/debug/libbpp-seq.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/release/bpp-seq.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/debug/bpp-seq.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/libbpp-seq.a

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/release/ -lbpp-core
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/debug/ -lbpp-core
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/ -lbpp-core

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/include

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/release/libbpp-core.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/debug/libbpp-core.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/release/bpp-core.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/debug/bpp-core.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../local/bpp/dev/lib/libbpp-core.a
```

To the .pro files but then hitting Run results in `error while loading shared libraries: libbpp-seq.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I haven't tried to include the .so files, only the .a files with the Add Library Wizard :S

Comment: Try to also add `PRE_TARGETDEPS += /local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/lib/libbpp-seq.a` and `PRE_TARGETDEPS += /local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/lib/libbpp-core.a`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you build the executable GUI as a static program as well, it can use static libraries and load dynamically (.so). So I gather the library you created was linked statically and the 3rd party (`libbpp`) was dynamic.

To build a static executable requires all libraries also be linked statically. So if you have a static library installed for `libppp` you should be able to make a static QT application (assuming it is a supported project type in QT).

As for the shared object error message. If you want your app to run outside of QT your going to have to add something like this to `/etc/ld.conf`

```
/local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/lib
```

This adds the path of your bpp libraries to the dynamic loader search path. After making the change to `/etc/ld.conf` you need to run this command:

```
ldconfig
```

I don't know the internal workings of QT but it likely works because behind the scenes it manually adds /local/yrq12edu/local/bpp/dev/lib to the search path for library objects (without modifying /etc/ld.conf)

Specifically compiling an executable as `-static` will produce errors if you are attempting to dynamic load anything at link time. As well to get a completely static binary you need to use the static version of the runtimes (c/c++). With GCC you can force usage of the static C runtime with `-static-libgcc` and with C++ use `-static-libstdc++` .